# How can I get colors to work in tldr plugin?

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

There's a plug-in (I believe this to be the right term) which is called '[tldr](https://tldr.sh/)'. On the `tldr` page, you can see this screenshot:

[image]

While I do have some color plug-ins installed (such as colorls and some syntax coloring plug-in), I don't get colored text when I use `tldr`:

[image]

How can I make it to work like the screenshot on their official page?

Comment: https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr-node-client/blob/master/README.md#configuration

Comment: Hi @muru , thanks! I tried that, and it gives me "command not found" for every line in .tldrrc when I source it. Any idea why?

Comment: @idankor you are not supposed to source it. Sourcing means running something as a script in your current shell.

Comment: @muru it works! thanks :)

Comment: Nice! You can post an answer describing what you did

Answer (score 0):

Create `.tldr` in your home dir and add:

```
{
  "themes": {
    "ocean": {
      "commandName": "bold, cyan",
      "mainDescription": "",
      "exampleDescription": "green",
      "exampleCode": "cyan",
      "exampleToken": "dim"
    },
    "myOwnCoolTheme": {
      "commandName": "bold, red",
      "mainDescription": "underline",
      "exampleDescription": "yellow",
      "exampleCode": "underline, green",
      "exampleToken": ""
    }
  },
  "theme": "ocean"
}
```